# EL and Scriptlets how to get pageContext.getAttribute children?

Tags: jsp, el

Is there an easy way for a scriptlet to access a field from a result as below? What should it look like?

`${item.options}` is not written as `<%= pageContext.getAttribute("item.options") %>`

I know I can set a new pageContext variable and access that. But I thought there might be a more elegant way...

I know that scriptlets are not ideal, but I am just prototyping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) and you should get the `${item}` directly instead of its `options` property which is not stored as a separate attribute or something. Given that it's an instance of class `Item`, here's how you can get it:

```
Item item = (Item) pageContext.findAttribute("item");
```

Then just call the `getOptions()` method on it.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) - explains also how EL works under the hood

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for the unbelievably quick answer. That's exactly what I needed. The Wiki page is excellent too.

Comment: I also found it interesting to read the generated java file. I suppose it would be acceptable to hijack the internal functions? Hmm... Maybe not...

i.e. 

`${item.title}` 

translates to...

`out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${item.title}", java.lang.String.class, (javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null, false));`

Comment: It would tight couple your code to the specific servletcontainer make/version and thus make your webapp totally unportable across various containers. You may get a better answer if you elaborate in detail the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that this is the right solution.